# Argument 1 passed to controller must be an instance of Illuminate\Http\Request?

Tags: php, validation, laravel

I am pretty new to laravel, and have searched everywhere but could not fix this error:

> Argument 1 passed to InsertController::insert() must be an instance of Illuminate\Http\Request, none given

I am trying to validate my input by passing in the Request method so I don't have to re-write a new validate method for every form, but it seems to always give me this error.

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Routing\Controller;

class InsertController extends Controller {

    public function insert(Request $request) {
        $username = Input::get('username');
        $pw = Hash::make(Input::get('pw'));
        $email = Input::get('email');

        $this->validate($request, ['name' => 'required|unique:users', 
                            'password' => 'required|min:8|max:255',
                            'email' => 'required|email|unique:users']); 


        if(!$validator->fails()) {
            $user = DB::table('users')->insert(
            ['email' => $email, 'password' => $pw, 'name' => $username]);
        }
    }

}
```

Here is the route I'm calling it with as well.

```
Route::post('users', ['uses' => 'InsertController@insert', 'before' => 'csrf'], function()
{
    $users = User::all(); //call the User model for all data in users table
    return View::make('users')->with('users', $users);
});
```

Comment: How are you calling that controller? Could you paste a part of your routes.php?

Comment: @jedrzej.kurylo I edited in the route

Comment: And what is this function you pass as third argument to Route::post()?

Comment: Which version of Laravel are you using?

Comment: @jedrzej.kurylo 4.2.17, and I'm not sure what that part means exactly yet.  I saw function() at the end of every route in every tutorial I found

Comment: @austin43 as far as I know is the 'Request' injection a feature of Laravel 5

Comment: @dschniepp Oh is that it? This is a brand new project so I should probably just upgrade to 5.

Comment: @austin43 i would do so, further more you can create custom request with an build in validation. http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/validation#form-request-validation

Comment: @dschniepp Ok I will do that.  Thanks for all the help everyone.

Answer (score 4):

The reason why it is not working is because of the given code relays on the injection of *Request*-Object, which was introduced with **Laravel 5** but the installed framework version is **4.2.17**.

To solve the issue you can remove the *Request*-Object from the method signature or update Laravel to 5.